# What namespace do I need to import to get the RavenDB type 'IndexQuery'?

Tags: c#, linq, namespaces, lucene, ravendb

In this code, there is a red squiggly lines under `IndexQuery`, `PatchRequest`, and `PatchCommandType`, indicating that the proper namespace is not imported. **What namespace do I need to import?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Raven.Client.Document;

...

documentStore.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("DataByColor",
new IndexQuery
{
    Query = "Color:red"
}, new[]
{
        new PatchReques
        {
            Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
            Name = "Color",
            Value = "Green"
        }
},
allowStale: false);
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you put the cursor over the class name and hit the ctrl-. (control-period), it will give you a list of suggested namespaces.  Don't know if this will work for namespaces/assemblies outside of the .NET framework, but I've found it to be quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Raven.Abstractions.Data;
```

Is the solution.

Comment: If it is, then you can mark it as the aswer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already referenced the assembly from your project, invoke the *View / Object Browser*, browse to the assembly's node and expand it. You'll see all the namespaces this assembly implements, and types under each of these namespaces.